# Locally patch missing Python type annotations?

Tags: python, static-typing, mypy, typeshed

Python now supports type hinting, so... yay! It seems like a great method to avoid some of the more obscure runtime bugs.

Sadly, third-party library support remains an issue. Though partially solved by the [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/third_party/3/lxml) project, which is also used by [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy), when trying to port some of my code to use type hints, I ran into issues due to missing stubs.

E.g.

```
# file:mypytest.py
import lxml.etree as et
tree = et.fromstring('<root><a>1</a><b>2</b><a>3</a></root>')
items = tree.xpath('/root/a')
print([i.text for i in items])
```

will work perfectly well, but mypy will produce the spurious error message

```
>>> mypy mypytest.py
mypytest.py:3: error: "_Element" has no attribute "xpath"
```

because the stub is currently incomplete.

For a larger project, downloading the stub from typeshed, adding the missing entries, and maybe  even submitting the corresponding pull request is a no-brainer.

But is there some method to monkey-patch the missing information in quick-and-dirty scenarios?

### Bad workaround

The best I was able to come up with was

```
items = tree.xpath('/root/a') # type: ignore
```

which silences the error, but also disables type-checking where the variable `items` is used afterwards. E.g. `items[0] + 1` will not cause a warning anymore.

In order to preserve type-checking it is possible to use

```
items_tmp = tree.xpath('/root/a') # type: ignore
items = items_tmp # type: List[et._Element]
```

but this seems hackish; It also has to be repeated everywhere the `.xpath` method is used.

Update from 2017-09-12: Alternatively one can use the syntax

```
items_tmp : List[et._Element] = tree.xpath('/root/a') # type: ignore
```